# Accepted self-answers with a score of 0 or less shouldn't prevent a question from Roombaing

Tags: feature-request, self-answer, automatic-deletion

I recently encountered a question that had a score of -4 and had been put "on hold" as off-topic. However, the OP had written a self-answer and accepted it. Currently, the question won't Roomba, even though the answer has a score of 0.

Should questions like this actually be prevented from Roombaing?

Comment: Or just ignore acceptance for roomba purpose altogether; it does not say anything about how useful the question is for those other than the OP.

Comment: @Alex That was my thought as well. In this case, literally no one other than the OP thought that there was anything useful about the post.